# Warning: Division by zero in /home … on line 4

Tags: php

One my Wordpress site  I got and error message:

> Warning: Division by zero in /home/acheung/oceanix.io/wp-content/themes/t-one/templates/portfolio.php on line 4

...and my line 4 looks like this:

```
$columns_class = 12 / $columns; ?>
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Check whether $columns is set to 0 first?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you tell me how to? I am not familiar with php at all. thank you.

Comment: If this is a theme you have made do as @MarkBaker has suggested. if it's a third party theme you downloaded see if you can get an older version and check if it gives the same error and work your way back until you get a stable one and contact the developer indicating which version this problem has first appeared in

Comment: `$columns_class = 12 / (($columns == 0) ? 1 : $columns);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix: Edit line 4 to

```
$columns_class = 12 / max(1, $columns);
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work now!